# Java's ServerSocketChannel.getLocalAddress() differs from InetSocketAddress passed to bind()

Tags: java, nio

If I bind to a specific interface using a specific hostname and then use ServerSocketChannel.getLocalAddress() to retreive the bound address, the hostname is longer there.

Is this by design or just undefined behavior? Is there any way to fix that?

```
InetSocketAddress bindTo = new InetSocketAddress("my-hostname", 9999);
ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(bindTo);
InetSocketAddress localAddr = (InetSocketAddress) serverSocketChannel.getLocalAddress();
System.out.println(bindTo);
System.out.println(localAddr);

> my-hostname/10.20.200.201:9999
> /10.20.200.201:9999
```

"my-hostname" in the above example is one of several hostnames that will resolve to the local IP. It is, however, not the hostname to which the IP resolves to when doing a reverse lookup.

The reason I ask is that I use a framework which will bind and then publish the service information to a central registry. However, it retrieves the bound address using .getLocalAddress() which ultimately ends up publishing the wrong hostname.

Answer (score 0):

> the hostname is longer there

You mean "the hostname is longer there" *in the String returned by `InetAddress.toString().`* There's nothing that obliges that behaviour. The local address to which a socket is bound is primarily an IP address. If you want to map it to a hostname, that's up to you.

Comment: InetSocketAddress will store the hostname and return it unchanged as long as it resolves. However, `ServerSocketChannel.getLocalAddress()` returns something else. I understand that the sockets binds to an IP address, I'm just curious as to why the information disappears.